# Tiktok Login Kit and Video Kit

Tags: reactjs, authentication, video, native, tiktok

Is there any steps or tutorials on **integrating [tiktok api](https://developers.tiktok.com)** with **[react native](https://reactnative.dev)** app ?
If it can be do with Tiktok web api also fine. Please tell me the procedures, i cant find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this React Native wrapper around the official APIs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tiktok